# How to remove the right click event for menu in JFace

Tags: java, swt, jface

How can I remove the event trigger for right click menu in JFace? Because I want to change it to left click instead. I used the SelectionEvent to trigger my menu.

So I used this code to display the menu using left click, but I still can display the menu using right click.

```
Menu menu = new Menu( getTable() );
getTable().setMenu( menu );

Button button = new Button( composite, SWT.NONE );
button.setText( "click me" );
button.addSelectionListener( new SelectionAdapter() {
    public void widgetSelected( SelectionEvent event ) {
        menu.setVisible( true );
    }
})
```

Comment: If you don't want the right click menu why call `setMenu` in the first place?

Comment: @greg-449 even I questioned that one, so I removed it and it works just the way I want it.

Answer (score 0):

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            if (arg0.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
                System.out.println("Left button clicked");
            } else if (arg0.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON2){
                System.out.println("Middle button clicked");
            } else if (arg0.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                System.out.println("Right button clicked");
            } 
        }
    });
```